# MySQL UPDATE fields FROM SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

I want to update some results in a table that would match a few conditions (i.e. variables from other tables to match a SELECT statement)

I've found something similar to this, on the net:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM score_test,score_2,score_3, etc WHERE score=20000 AND score_test.id=score_2.id AND etc.. FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE score_test SET name='Test';
COMMIT;
```

**NOTE**: UPDATE score_test SET ... WHERE does not satisfy my needs as I need to gather the results that satisfy the SELECT statement

But it didn't work. It updates all my fields. What I am looking for is a syntax to use to UPDATE only the RESULTS from the SELECT statement.

My database is split into 10-15 tables and conditions may vary as I have to update some fields that STRICTLY accomplish some conditions that depend on the queries from other tables.

Answer (score 3):

SQL `UPDATE` statements accept `WHERE` clauses just like `SELECT` statements do:

```
UPDATE score_test SET name='Test' WHERE score=20000;
```

## edit

You can also treat the part following `UPDATE` as roughly the same as the part of a `SELECT` which follows `FROM`, which means you can do joins:

```
UPDATE score_test 
  JOIN test ON test.id=score_test.test_id
SET score_test.name = 'Test'
WHERE score_test.score=20000
```

The hints for this are in [the UPDATE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), where it uses the `table_reference` symbol in the syntax definition. The syntax for `table_reference` is defined [on the JOIN page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Implying identical treatment in both `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries.

## note on `FOR UPDATE`

the `FOR UPDATE` clause in a `SELECT` statement does not *actually* do anything related to updates... it only gathers a lock on the rows. You still need to follow that with an appropriate `UPDATE` query which does all the necessary JOINS and WHEREs (likely the same as your `SELECT`)

Comment: I know that. But what happens when I have UPDATE score_test SET name='Test' WHERE score=20000, table2.userstats='100', table3.whatever='cool', table3.yey='nothing', table....; ? Considering that SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE conditions... AND userid.table1=userid.table2, userid.table1=userid.table2...

Comment: See edited answer, you can "select" multiple tables for update inside the UPDATE statement, and simply specify the qualified column name for setting values.

Comment: I've got to use multiple tables.

Comment: I'm not sure if the timing of that last comment was before or after you saw my answer edit. Let me know if I can elaborate further.

Comment: Hmm, it worked, thank you very much :) It should do what I need it to! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" (instead of changing the title to include (solved)) before you totally move on ;-) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish what you are asking. The simplest to just satisfy your question is to just do an update.

`UPDATE score_test SET name='Test' WHERE score=20000;`

If you want to satisfy conditions from multiple tables, you can use joins, just like a select statement, in the update statement.

You can further accomplish your goals, if you have such a complex use case, by creating a temporary table that holds the IDs of the items you want to edit, and cull that table one by one through multiple `DELETE` queries until you have the set you want to update.